# android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode dynamically from code

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I have next configuration in my accessibility service.

```
android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
```

Sometimes I need have this value as false.
How can I set this value to false from my java code?

Thanks.

Comment: Not supported. This must be statically defined in your service metadata, since it must be read by the system before your service process can be started.

Comment: @alanv, Thanks. Please make an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this attribute may not be configured dynamically. It is needed by the system to determine what permissions your service needs before the service may be started.

Please check the documentation for [AccessibilityServiceInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html) for fields that may be configured at run-time.